# Alice and Bob play a game on a graph G alternately choosing distinct vertices. Alice starts by choosing any vertex.

Tags: graph-theory

Each subsequent choice must be adjacent to the most recent choice of the other player.Thus, together they follow a path. The last player able to move wins. Who has a winning strategy that always works no matter how the other player plays? Intuitively, I believe Alice will win because she's limiting Bob to the vertex that she ends off with. I don't know if that's the idea. Any help would be great.

Comment: Are you not allowed to repeat a choice?

Comment: Clearly there is no general strategy that works for all graphs, because on a cycle all choices (essentially) are determined.  If the cycle has odd length Alice wins, even length Bob wins.

Comment: A path doesn't contain a repeated edge.

Comment: David, that was what I was thinking.